What is the equivalent schematic of a center tap potentiometer?
I'm wondering what is the equivalent schematic of a center tap potentiometer (in order to simulate it).
For example, I have a fixed point connected to the GND and the wiper on the right, what is the equivalent schematic of this?


To clarify: are you connecting anything to the ends of the resistive element? Is the wiper a separate terminal from the tap?

If we consider the CT pot rotation X from CCW to CW represented by -1 to +1 with 0 representing the center of rotation, then we can simulate it with one of the following, where the resistor R2 and R2' have the same resistance as the element of R1 and R1' and is half the total centre-tapped pot element resistance.:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If X >= 0 then use the left schematic and pot R1 will have rotation 0 to 1 for X from 0 to 1.
If X < 0 then R1' then use the right schematic and R1' will have rotation 1 to 0 for X from 0 to -1.  (pot R1' rotation = 1+X)
A more realistic model would have some wiper resistance and might have a bit of a dead spot in the centre.

You can replace the center tap potentiometer with two ordinary potentiometers connected in a bridge circuit. Here are a few typical cases (K1 and K2 reflect the positions of the wipers).
K1 = 0.5, K2 = 0.5

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
K1 = 1, K2 = 0.5

simulate this circuit
K1 = 0.5, K2 = 1

simulate this circuit
... etc.

The text uses K1 and K2, whereas the schematics use P1 and P2. Is that a typo?

@Chester Gillon, "P" is the designation for a potentiometer (the more standard designation is "R"). "K" is the voltage division ratio r2/(r1 + r2), which varies from 0 to 1 as the wiper is moved.

thanks for the explanations, for a 50k pot, does it mean that each pot is a 50k ?

@exolune, The input source "sees" it as two potentiometers in parallel, while the load "sees" only one potentiometer. So this 50k "center-tapped potentiometer" should be considered as composed of two 100k potentiometers.

You would need to simulate it with three resistors in series, with one resistor junction being the pot wiper position, and one being the fixed connection.  The total series resistance of the three would equal the pot resistance.  Changing the wiper position would require recalculation of all three resistor values.
